# How to to attach URL image to an email using nodemail?

Tags: node.js, request, nodemailer

I am trying to attach an image via url link to an email I am sending. Here is my code,

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");

exports.index = function index(req, res){
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
        service: 'yahoo',
        auth: {
            user: '__@yahoo.co.uk',
            pass: '_'
        }
    });
    var attachedfile;

        request.get('http://i.imgur.com/iIAS1wE.jpg', function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                attachedfile = body;
            }
        });
        var options = {
            from: '__@yahoo.co.uk',
            to: '__@yahoo.co.uk',
            subject: 'hello',
            text: 'hello! See attached files',
            attachments: [
            {filename: 'starwars.jpg', contents: attachedfile }]
        }
        transporter.sendMail(options , function(err, response){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + response.message);
        }
        transporter.close();
        });
    res.render('email/index');
}
```

But there is no image when I check the email...what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nodemailer automatically fetches and attaches files from provided URLs. Here's a [detailed guide of different ways to attach files](https://community.nodemailer.com/using-attachments/).

```
attachments: [{
        filename: "iIAS1wE.jpg",
        path: "http://i.imgur.com/iIAS1wE.jpg",
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch manually the files (in case you dont send bulk emails),
nodemailer can do it for you:

```
 attachments: [
            {path: 'http://i.imgur.com/iIAS1wE.jpg'}]
```

Comment: Hmm, I have tried this but the image file is not attached to the email sent.

Comment: I have finally managed to figure it out, is 'filePath', not 'file'.